# Mui visual bug with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I have a login page made with Mui components, the problem is when I have a saved username and password and it tries to autofill the field. The autocomplete information and the placeholder collapsed

Bug Screenshot

[image: 1]

The problem is solved when I click anywhere on the page.

I'm using useForm too.

Here is my code

```
<Controller
                name='email'
                control={control}
                rules={{ required: 'El correo electrónico es requerido' }}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <TextField
                    label='Correo electrónico'
                    size='small'
                    error={!!errors.email}
                    helperText={errors.email?.message}
                    fullWidth
                    {...field}
                  />
                )}
 />

<Controller
                name='password'
                control={control}
                rules={{ required: 'La contraseña es requerida' }}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <TextField
                    label='Contraseña'
                    type='password'
                    size='small'
                    error={!!errors.password}
                    helperText={errors.password?.message}
                    fullWidth
                    {...field}
                  />
                )}
              />
```

I tried to set a default value prop in the textField but is not working.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help you. Add this prop in `<Textfield>`

```
InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
```